# How does the mergeAll works?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to figure out, how `mergeAll` works and created examples:

```
const clicks = Rx.Observable.interval(4000).map(()=> "first");
const higherOrder = clicks.map((ev) => Rx.Observable.interval(1000).map(() => "inner").take(10));
const firstOrder = higherOrder.mergeAll();
firstOrder.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

the output it always `inner` and `first` never outputted. After calling `mergeAll()` the `clicks` observable is no more relevant?

On more example:

```
const input = document.getElementById("window");

const clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup').map(() => "Hello");
const interval = Rx.Observable.interval(4000);
const result = clicks.window(interval)
    .map(win => {
        return win.take(1);
    })
    .mergeAll(); // flatten the Observable-of-Observables
result.subscribe(x => console.log("Result " + x));
```

on subscribe, I've got the result from outer observable "Result Hello" not the inner observable. What kind of role plays `mergeAll` in this case?
Why the `win` variable is an instance `observable` not `Hello`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> After calling mergeAll() the clicks observable is no more relevant?

Correct. You map each individual click to a stream of `"inner"` events. `mergeAll` simply merges those streams together. The click event lives in this resulting stream only very faintly as the point in time where a specific merged stream starts. It becomes a bit more clear this way:

```
const clicks$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
const higherOrder$ = clicks$.map(click => Rx.Observable.interval(500)
  .map(counter => `${click}–${counter}`)
);
higherOrder$.mergeAll().subscribe(console.log);
```

The [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeAll) and its marble diagram might also help you understand:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should use switchMap.

```
firstOrder.switchMap(x => console.log(x)).subscribe( value => console.log(value));
```

or

```
result.switchMap(x => console.log("Result " + x)).subscribe( value => console.log(value));
```

switch expects a stream of `Observables`, when it get an Observable pushed onto it’s input stream it unsubscribes from any previous Observables and subscribes to the new one and then emits any values from that Observable onto it’s output stream.